# Reference to XML file is not a member of the R file

Tags: android, android-manifest

How can I had to class layout in R another XML file?

It should be automatic as I had new resources to res, but it's not.
Someone knows what I did wrong?

I open an activity and now I want to open another activity that will work with another XML
example.
I have menu and main.xml.
Now I want to go for another activity called gamescreen using this method:

```
newGameButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = = new Intent(this, gameScreen.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }

}
```

I want to move to another "page" to another activity called gameScreen which should be associated to the XML called gameScreen.xml.

But in its onCreate:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.gameScreen);
```

}

and gameScreen is not a member of the R file.

The main problem is that when I add resource to layout for example newxmlfile.xml
the R file doesn't do any work and stays in this state.

```
public static final class layout {
    public static final int main=0x7f030000;
}where it should have been:
public static final class layout {
    public static final int main=0x7f030000;
    public static final int newxmlfile=0x7f031000;
}
```

Comment: after doing clean its doesnt even recognize R.layout.main
what is wrong outthere

Answer (score 0):

If your file does exists in the `res/layout` folder, and probably you are in a different package, you have to import the reference to `R`, and remove any reference to `android.R`

```
import com.mypkg.R;
```

Also don't forget to add class `gameScreen` to your manifest file as activity.

**EDIT**

You should recreate the XML file with the wizard, and make sure everything is fine there. Compare against to some samples located in the SDK's install `/samples/` directory.

Comment: it doesnt work it's not recognised as a layout resource.
maybe something involve new settings somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

You have got to add the new activity to the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
...
<activity 
    android:name=".gameScreen">
</activity>
```

**Edit:**
This is assuming gameScreen is the Class name of the new activity.
Also, from what I understand, gameScreen is an XML file located in res/layout.
The filename of `gameScreen.xml` must be lowercase: `gamescreen.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

Use aapt(exe is present in platforms/<platform>/tools/aapt) command to generate the R file :

aapt  package -f -M ${manifest.file} -F ${packaged.resource.file} -I ${path.to.android-jar.library} -S ${android-resource-directory} [-m -J  ${folder.to.output.the.R.java}]

It will generate a new R.java file. If there is any error then it will show you that as well.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse: menu-project-clean-choose your project.

If not, check gameScreen.xml is under the res layout folder.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.
Somehow Eclipse did

```
 import Android.R;
```

which caused ambiguity on the R variable.